# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function Reactjs 16.6.3

Tags: reactjs

this is my first reactjs app using hooks, i'm facing an error

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

, my code: 
`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Test from './Test';

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

`Test.jsx`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function Test(props) {
  const [name, ChangeName] = useState('Zeyad');

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => ChangeName(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

here's the full error:
[image]

I don't know what's wrong in my code?

Comment: You don't get information about what file and what line this error occurs in?

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson I provided it.

Comment: I've not used `useState` before, but I understand it's not in React v16.6.3, but in `React v16.7.0-alpha`. Could that be the problem? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: Oh oh! you're right!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`useState` is not available in `Reactjs v16.6.3`, you will have to upgrade to the newest version of React, or at least to `React v16.8.0`

[reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this issue simply upgrade to the latest version of react that supports hooks. 
Note, you need both library **react** and **react-dom**

As of now this will work,

```
npm install react-dom@16.8.0-alpha.0
npm install react@16.8.0-alpha.0
```

Please make sure you have the correct version, here is the is available versions list for [react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react?activeTab=versions) & [react-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom?activeTab=versions)

Read more about this feature in this intro [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)